# Ruby error evaluating function `font-url`: undefined method `path_to_asset' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, less, asset-pipeline, sprockets

I'm new to Ruby *and* Rails. I've implemented a module to allow me to manually compile LESS to CSS for my project to avoid using Sprockets, as it doesn't allow me to compile different LESS for each user.

When compiling LESS I randomly get the following error about 40% of the time. 60% of the time the LESS compiles correctly.

```
error evaluating function `font-url`: undefined method `path_to_asset' for nil:NilClass
```

What could be causing this, and why is it random?

Cheers,
-JC

**Update:**
Added a code sample:

```
# Prepare the body of the file.
body = File.read(@app_file_name_full)
body = ERB.new(body).result(binding)  # Bind to the @instance variables in this module.

# Parse with LESS.
begin
  body = Less::Parser.new({
    paths: [@assets_path, "/usr/local/share/gems/gems/twitter-bootstrap-rails-3.2.2/vendor/toolkit/"],
    filename: @final_file_name,
    compress: true
  }).parse(body).to_css
rescue Exception => err
  puts "LESS PARSING FAILED! ", err.message
  body = nil
end
```

Comment: can you post the code which throws this error?

Comment: @KapitulaAlexey: Done :)